# Unable to do npm install for angular2 project

Tags: angular, npm

**I am trying to create an application with .net and Angular2.**

When i do npm install i get the following error [image]

npm error comes on many lines  saying **npm ERR!** 
How do i create an angular2 app with success full npm install

> I have  `package.json` as follows

```
     {
       "name": "angular-quickstart",
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "scripts": {
       "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
       "lite": "lite-server",
       "tsc": "tsc",
       "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
       },
       "licenses": [
       {
       "type": "MIT",
       "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
       }
       ],
       "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
        "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
        "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
        "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
        "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
        "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "systemjs": "0.19.39",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
        },
       "devDependencies": {
       "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
       "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
        "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
        "typescript": "^2.0.3"
        }
        }
```

Comment: package.json is absent

Comment: I had added package.json before as in Angular2 website.As it did not work   i removed node.js.Unable to install right now.Once node.js is reinstalled i will update.

Comment: Try updating node - https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: seems as if that is true.My node version is a bit old

Answer (score 0):

Check Node js version  using `node -v`  and npm using `npm -v`

> Version require For node **v4.x.x or higher**  and  For npm  **3.x.x or higher**

if not then installed latest nodejs from [Here](https://nodejs.org/en/)

And for Npm try

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

then install the packages listed in package.json with the command

```
npm install
```

Comment: my current version is 0.8.16.Seems to be the problem.I am having problems installing newer versions of node.Once i fix that i will update